# tslint Error - Shadowed name: 'err'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, lint, tslint

tslint is currently throwing the following error

```
Shadowed name: 'err'
```

Here is the code

```
fs.readdir(fileUrl, (err, files) => {
        fs.readFile(path.join(fileUrl, files[0]), function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Anybody have a clue on what the best way would be to solve this and what the error even means?

Comment: It means you've shadowed the name `err`; you're using the same name for the error in two nested callbacks, so the outer error is inaccessible in the inner callback body. As to how to solve it: use a different name for one of them.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are using the same variable "err" in both outer and inner callbacks, which is prevented by tslint.

If you want to use the same variable then "no-shadowed-variable": false, otherwise do as below.

```
fs.readdir(fileUrl, (readDirError, files) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(fileUrl, files[0]), function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: In this context what is 'err' value? where is that var defined?

Answer (score 5):

Add this comment just above the error line--

> > **// tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable**

Answer (score 3):

This shadowed name tslint error is due to repetition of the name 'err' twice in your callback functions. You can change either anyone 'err' to other name so this should work.

Example: This should work

```
fs.readdir(fileUrl, (error, files) => {
        fs.readFile(path.join(fileUrl, files[0]), function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

When same variable is declared multiple times in same scope, this warning occurs.

Use different variable names in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

this line will disable your error,

```
// tslint:disable: no-shadowed-variable
```

but it's not okay to have tow err variables you can also change the second err variable name to something different

```
fs.readdir(fileUrl, (err, files) => {
  fs.readFile(path.join(fileUrl, files[0]), function (readFileErr, data) {        
    if (!readFileErr) {
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I had an error like this `interfaces.ts:119:26 - Shadowed name: 'POST'`

```
// tslint:disable: no-shadowed-variable
interface API {
   export namespace APINAME {
     export type POST {

     }
   }
   export namespace OTHERAPINAME {
     export type POST {

     }
   }
}
```

I have disabled this error case with this line `// tslint:disable: no-shadowed-variable` because sometimes typescript compiler cannot understand your code right :)